# Validation Error In Visual Studio Code with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, visual-studio-code

Below is the my mongodb `schema` **Product** with six fields - **username**, **email**, **bio**, **image**, **hash** and **salt** :

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        username: {
            type: String,
            lowercase: true,
            required: [true, "can't be blank"],
            index: true,
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            lowercase: true,
            required: [true, "can't be blank"],
            index: true,
        },
        bio: String,
        image: String,
        hash: String,
        salt: String,
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
```

My Data/Product.js Info, data stored in the database:

```
[
    {
        username: "USERNAME",
        email: "name.username@gmail.com",
        bio: "BIOSample",
        image: "Image",
        hash: "sample",
        salt: "sample",
    },
];
```

My Controller Code:

```
const Product = require("../models/product");

//create new product => /api/v1/product/new
exports.newProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
    const product = await Product.create(req.body);
    res.status(201).json({
        success: true,
        product,
    });
};
```

While npm run I get this error message as shown below:

```
Product validation failed: email: can't be blank, username: can't be blank.
```

Comment: What happens when you do console.log(req.body)?

Comment: If so then, don't write `required: [true, "can't be blank"]` . You need to just write `required: true`. And further validation you can make it in the front-end if you have or else, write a validation function in nodejs for **email** and **username**

Answer (score 2):

If the error that you are getting is

> Product validation failed: email: can't be blank, username: can't be
> blank.

Then probably, don't use the **required** as `required: [true, "can't be blank"]` . Maybe because of that you might get the error.

You need to just write `required: true` . And also you need to write your further validation for your *email* and *username*, that you can make it in the front-end if you have your code or else, write a validation function in nodejs for *email* and *username* . where it satisfies your condition.

Something like this code below, This is for you to understand:

```
const Joi = require("joi");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Genre, validateGenre, genreSchema } = require("./genre");
Joi.objectId = require("joi-objectid")(Joi);

const movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 50,
    },
    numberInStock: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 255,
        default: 13,
    },
    dailyRentalRate: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0,
        max: 255,
        required: true,
    },
    liked: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    genre: {
        type: genreSchema,
        required: true,
    },
});

const Movie = mongoose.model("Movie", movieSchema);

function validateMovie(movie) {
    const schema = {
        title: Joi.string().required().min(5).max(255),
        numberInStock: Joi.number().required().min(0).max(255),
        dailyRentalRate: Joi.number().required().min(0).max(255),
        liked: Joi.boolean(),
        // genreId: Joi.string().required()
        genreId: Joi.objectId().required(),
        _id: Joi.objectId(),
    };
    return Joi.validate(movie, schema);
}

module.exports.Movie = Movie;
module.exports.validateMovie = validateMovie;
```

Here above I have written a **validation function** for **movieSchema**.

So same way you too can write validation function:

```
const Joi = require("joi");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
Joi.objectId = require("joi-objectid")(Joi);

var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        username: {
            type: String,
            lowercase: true,
            required: true,
            index: true,
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            lowercase: true,
            required: true,
            index: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        bio: String,
        image: String,
        hash: String,
        salt: String,
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
const Product = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);


function validateProduct(product) {
    const schema = {
        username: Joi.string().required(),
        email: Joi.string().required().email(),
        bio: Joi.string().required(),
        image: Joi.string().required(),
        hash: Joi.string().required(),
        salt: Joi.string().required(),
        _id: Joi.objectId(),
    };
    return Joi.validate(product, schema);
}

module.exports.Product = Product;
module.exports.validateProduct = validateProduct;
```

You need to do `npm install joi` for **Joi** to work. https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi

Comment: After typing: required: true,
the error now is:
Product validation failed: email: Email Required, username: Username Required.

Comment: you need to type proper format of **email** like: abcd@gmail.com.